# Get timestamp of user's last visit from database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I have a DB that looks like so:

[image]

For every event, i.e. click, a row is added, where `UserID` is a unique cookie that identifies each visitor, and `timestamp` is when the event happened (here I'm using basic numbers, for simplicity).

How can I, with pure SQL, get a table that gives me the timestamp of the last visit of each user? So, if I did it with my sample, I'd get this:

[image]

with rejected rows in red and selected ones in green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(Timestamp)
FROM <YourTable>
GROUP BY UserID
```